# Can Signal Handler be executed before establishing it's handler ? How is it possible?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

Can Signal Handler be executed before establishing it's handler ? How is it possible ?

Why behavior is undefined if :
thread 'A' is calling sigsetjmp and establishing signal handler for SIGALRM.
then thread 'A' is interrupted by SIGALRM, then signal handler is executed by another thread 'B' who is calling siglongjmp.

Comment: I don't think it is undefined behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761135/530160

Comment: Can you show us some sample code and a reference that says it's exhibiting undefined behaviour? Then we'll be better able to answer your question.